# Can't retrieve the JSON Post data, file_get_contents('php://input') is empty

Tags: php, json

Guys I'm having the weirdest, head splitting issue ever. I know it has been asked many times before but none of the answers shed light on my issue and I can't get it working.

Problem: `file_get_contents('php://input')` returns NULL no matter what I try.

### Things I've tried/checked so far:

- allow_url_fopen is on
- echo $_POST; didn't work either
- php://input used only once in the PHP code (v5,6)

### I get NULL when I do this;

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
var_dump($data);
```

### My Goal:

I'll just parse the response sent by the payment processor and do some stuff with it.

### JSON sent from the payment processor;

Activity logs in my dashboard show that this JSON data is being sent successfully upon new subscription.
https://codebeautify.org/jsonviewer/cb44885d

Any advice is highly appreciated, it's been 12 hours and I'm still stuck with it.

Comment: what about post\get ?

Comment: @rtfm Are you asking the type of the webhook? It's POST. Sorry, should have added this in there.

Comment: Is this coming from your own payment processor or does it have a name?

Comment: if they are posting to your url then just use $_POST.

Comment: 1) Make sure you can see any errors that might be occurring ~ `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 'On');`. 2) Check the JSON string before trying to decode it ~ `$json = file_get_contents('php://input'); echo $json;` 3) Check for JSON errors ~ `if(empty($data)) { throw new Exception(json_last_error_msg()); }`

Comment: @mickmackusa It's FastSpring.

Comment: @rtfm Using `php://input` is the preferred way to read JSON request bodies

Comment: @cemakbulut what does the client-side code look like? How is the request constructed?

Comment: @Phil There's not much going on in the client-side. Some javascript code triggers a payment popup, upon (un)successful payment, a webhook gets fired and sent to a HTTPS endpoint, which I specified in my FastSpring dashboard.

Comment: @cemakbulut ok. Did you try my other suggestions?

Comment: @Phil Absolutely. Turned debugging on, but nothing shows up. I just don't know what to do. Maybe I should email the FastSpring, ask for a sample code or something?

Comment: @cemakbulut does the client-side code run in your browser? If so, look in the *Network* console. Find the request to your PHP file. If possible, post some screenshots of the request headers and payload